# Link between class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I have :

```
ClassAttribute:
    def __init__(self, string):
        ### example of string : 
        ###     "c1 int not null"
        splitted_string = string.split(' ', 2)
        self.col_name = splitted_string[0]
        self.col_def = splitted_string[1]
        if len(splitted_string) == 3:
            self.col_option = splitted_string[2]
        else:
            self.col_option = ""

ClassTable:
    def __init__(self, string):
        ### example of string : 
        ###     "create table TABLE_A (c1 int not null, c2 string)"
        string_splitted = string.split(' ', 3)
        self.table_name = string_splitted[2]
        ### In real life, I've a list of my attributes
        ### Example : 
        ###     list_attributes = ['c1 int not null', 'c2 string']
        self.table_attributes = []
        for attr in list_attributes:
            self.table_attributes.append(ClassAttribute(attr))
```

Questions :

1. How to call my attributes objects in my table without iterating over the list_attributes ? For example, I would like to add the "not null" option of the nth attributes, I don't know its position but I know its name.
2. From the attributes object, how to get the table name ?

Comment: To 1: if you know a name but not the position/index, you may be better off using a dict.

Comment: As for 2: you change the attribute class `__init__` to accept an extra argument, 'table', then you pass the table as `self` to your attribute class instantiation, and finally, store the 'table' argument as a member of your attribute instance.

Comment: Does it work? That should answer your question #2. (NB: I mentioned passing `self`, but I now notice you only want the table name. While having a reference to the actual table may prove more useful, you can of course just pass `self.table_name` instead of `self`.)

Comment: It works !!! Thx for your help. Dictionnaries was what i need...

Comment: Don't edit with a solution. Either add an answer, or delete the question.

Comment: Thanks, I also fixed the title. Don't forget to accept your answer when the system lets you.

Comment: Thx for your help Andras ! I can accept my answer in two days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Evert's suggestion works for me :

```
ClassAttribute:
    def __init__(self, table, string):
        splitted_string = string.split(' ', 2)
        self.table_name = table.table_name
        self.col_name = splitted_string[0]
        self.col_def = splitted_string[1]
        if len(splitted_string) == 3:
            self.col_option = splitted_string[2]
        else:
            self.col_option = ""

ClassTable:
    def __init__(self, string):
        string_splitted = string.split(' ', 3)
        self.table_name = string_splitted[2]
        self.table_attributes = []
        for attr in list_attributes:
            self.table_attributes.append(ClassAttribute(self, attr))
```